# New-AzureResourceGroup unauthorized in VSO build agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines

I have a build agent set up on a VM in Azure, that is linked to our Visual Studio Online.

I then have an Azure Powershell build step that runs a script that tries to execute New-AzureResourceGroup.

This results in the following:

New-AzureResourceGroup : Unauthorized

```
113 ##[error]At C:\BuildAgents\agent\_work\[...]\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:47 char:1
114 ##[error]+ New-AzureResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation ...
115 ##[error]+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
116 ##[error]+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureResourceGroup], CloudException
117 ##[error]+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupCommand
```

I can run these scripts locally with no problem.

I have tried importing a publish settings file in the script, but it seems New-AzureResourceGroup is not allowed authentication this way.

I run the build agent as a service under a local user account (not network service).

Does anyone know how to allow the build agent execute New-AzureResourceGroup?

I hope to be able to do a full continuous deployment including setting up and managing everything needed in Azure, including the resource groups.

**UPDATE**

According to the article below:

"If you connect using this method [publish settings file], you can only use the Azure Service Management (or the ASM mode) commands."

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-connect/

I'm assuming this applies to Azure powershell as well.

So, is there really no way of managing resources in azure without using account based authentication?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @bmoore-msft for providing the missing piece. I'll just add another screen shot of the link I needed to find to set up the build to run under an actual account.

[image: After clicking as prescribed in the answer below, click here:]

Comment: When you create the Azure PowerShell script do you try to set the Azure Subscription in the PowerShell script?

Comment: Yes. The scripts were fine, including specifying the subscription. Only thing missing was how to set up the build agent authenticate as an account as opposed to using a certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Azure Resource Manager you do have to use Azure Active Directory authentication, no certs.  So that applies to cli, PowerShell, REST APIs, etc.

In VSO there is a build task for Azure PowerShell.  When you use that task you specify a "connection" or subscription to execute the task as... so you save the creds in VSO.  You could use a regular PowerShell task, but then you would have to secure the creds yourself.

Finally, when you set up the account connection in VSO, it *must* be an orgID, MSAs are not supported (PowerShell limitation).  Service Principal support is coming.

[image: VSO Build Def]

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea as to why when setting this up to run under an orgID, the "live" build output broke? Now I suddenly need to wait for the build to finish to see what's going on.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - when you run the Azure PowerShell build task, you don't see the output from the script in the build output window?  Is that the question?

Comment: Yes. In the VSO build page, after clicking "Queue new build", I would normally see the script output while the build is running. After setting up the build step with an account, the output is empty, and I need to dowload the log to see what happened.

Comment: ok, I've noticed some odd "behaviors" with that window in the browser, sometimes it refreshes, sometimes not - but lmk if you're seeing it consistently.

Comment: Just so that people dont miss it, you have two Powershell steps available to you in VSO, one which is under Utility and the second one which is under Deployment. Make sure you add the second one as first one would not provide you the option of using subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a lot of trouble using the Azure Resource Manager with VSO.
I finally found a working solution to my problem by creating a Service Principal account with enough rights on the Azure subscription to deploy from Visual Studio Online.

I used this blog post from David Ebbo to create the Service Principal Account: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html

In VSO I removed the "Azure PowerShell" step and replaced it with a "PowerShell" step. In the PowerShell script I start with logging in the Service Principal account and then deploy my applications using Azure Resource Manager.

More details of my findings can be found on the MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d5a940e0-ed83-46ff-9efc-045fb9522c5b/ad-auth-from-azure-powershell-in-vso-fails-with-accessingwsmetadataexchangefailed?forum=azurescripting